# Time invariance of recursive system

Tags: discrete-signals

I am having trouble with figuring out if the following system is time-invariant (with $y[n]$ being the output and $x[n]$ being the input):
$$y[n] = 1.02 \cdot (y[n-1] + x[n])$$

I should also add that the initial rest conditions are :
$x[n] = 0 $ for $ n < 1 $
and $y[n] = 0 $ for $ n < 1 $

and lastly i managed to rewrite the above system's equation as a series :

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=1}^n x(k) \cdot a^{(n-k+1)}$$ where $$a = 1.02$$

I know the definition of time invariance and I have tried a couple of ways to work it out but I just can't figure out if that system is time invariant because of it's recursive nature . I would be very happy if someone could help me out.

Comment: Can you please show what you have done and where you are stuck. Recursion doesn't require any special treatment, so it's difficult to help you if we don't know where the hiccup is.

Comment: [related](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/67956/63763)

Answer (score 1):

To check for time-invariance/time-variance, one should check if delaying the input by some amount results in an output delayed by the same amount. The way I like to represent the above statement is through the following:
$$\mathcal{D\bigg\{\mathcal{T}\big\{x[n]\big\}\bigg\}} = \mathcal{T\bigg\{\mathcal{D}\big\{x[n]\big\}\bigg\}} \tag{1}$$
where $\mathcal{T}$ represents the transformation from input to output such that $\mathcal{T}\big\{x[n]\big\} = y[n]$ and $\mathcal{D}$ is a delay operator such that $\mathcal{D}\big\{x[n]\big\} = x[n-n_0]$. Let's re-write $(1)$
$$y[n-n_o] = \mathcal{T\bigg\{x[n-n_o]\bigg\}} $$

So now,

1. Compute $\mathcal{T\bigg\{x[n-n_0]\bigg\}}$
2. Compute $y[n-n_0]$

If they are equal, the system is time-invariant. If they aren't, the system is time-variant.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**

The problem here is that you do not have a well defined system. A system mathematically is an operator defined on a space of sequences (typically $\ell^2$ if you know what that means). An implication of this is that a system is a well defined function, that is, a map that takes an element and returns exactly one result. This is a property that your system, assuming it is defined by $T(x)=y$ does not have, since given a sequence $x[n]$, there is an infinite number of sequences $y[n]$ such that the recursive equation
$$ y[n]=1.02⋅(y[n−1]+x[n]) $$
holds.

**Time invariance check**

Let's assume that what you have actually is a well defined operator and try to prove its time invariance. First write
$$T(x)=y\quad\text{and}\quad T(x[l+\cdot\,])=z,$$
where $x[l+\cdot]$ is the shifted sequence.
In order to prove time invariance it would be enough to check that
$$y[l+\cdot\,]=z[\,\cdot\,].$$
Now observe that, by the definition of $T$
\begin{align}
y[n+l]&=1.02(y[n+l-1]+x[n+l])\\
z[n]&=1.02(z[n-1]+x[n+l]),
\end{align}
and then the condition $y[n+l]=z[n]$ is equivalent to $y[n+l-1]=z[n-1]$, that is, if the sequences $y[l+\cdot\,]$ and $z[\,\cdot\,]$ are identical at one point, they will be the same sequence at all points, however we can not say anything more.